# How to copy files to remote computer using Bash script?

Tags: bash, filesystems, credentials

I have a script that needs to copy a file to a remote computer:

```
cp -R "${DEST_FOLDER}" "${SRC_FOLDER}"
```

How can I do it when the remote computer requires user and password for access?

How do I login to this computer with a bash script?

Thanks

Comment: Use `scp` or `rsync` with public key authentication.

Comment: do what @Barmar said, or mount your remote dir to your system.

Answer (score 6):

Bash itself will not let you access remote host (obviously), but you could use SSH:

**Step 1:** On your local PC generate key to perform password-free authentication later

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

It will ask you to enter passphrase. If you want your bash script to be fully non-interactive, you can opt not to use any password.

**Step 2:** Copy you public key to the remote host:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remote-host
```

**Step 3:** Use `scp` to copy files:

```
$ scp -r local_file user@remote-host:/remote_dest_dir/
```

Comment: Empty-passphrase SSH keys make your remote system's security depend on your local machine (i.e., access to your private key file). The preferred thing would be to **not** leave the passphrase empty, and using `ssh-agent` / `keychain` so you have to enter your passphrase but once per session.